# Construct an Asp.Net auto-complete name picker

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, ajax, autocomplete

Here we go: Your typical absolutely web newbie question. :-)

How to build such Asp.Net name picker where I can collect a few names from a textbox separated by semicolons and then, after validation of some sort, mark those valid names in black underscore and invalid ones in red underscore. You know it's a little like the SharePoint name picker behavior.

I know jQuery and Ajax.Net already provide useful AutoComplete controls but I don't know how to enable the underscore style on top of those controls.

Hey btw I just noticed the 'Tags' textbox of posting question page here is pretty darn close to what I want so anyone knows how it's done?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use something like this http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/demo.html

Good luck!